Who could access the court of priests in Solomon's temple?
In the Herodian temple, the courts were divided into four partitions--the court of priests, the court of men, the court of women, and the court of gentiles. A thicker wall was placed between the inner courts (priests, men, women) and the outer court (gentiles). In contrast, Solomon's temple only had two partitions--the court of priests (the inner court) and the great court (the outer one). By the name, it would seem that the court of priests was only accessible to the priests, but if Herod's temple is an example to go off of, it seems that the people could go into the inner partition to some extent. Anybody have knowledge on this topic? Ezekiel 46:1-10 seems to describe some entrance into the inner court, but it is a bit technical and I'm not sure if the people can go into the court like the priest can.

Architectural ConfigurationAny answer must take into consideration that Herod's grand Temple in the first century, was not the same as Solomon's Temple in 1000 B.C. (known as the First Temple). The first Temple was demolished by the Babylonians in 586 B.C.  Herod's magnificent edifice (the Second Temple) was the pride and joy of his "personal" building spree.
And note that Ezekiel's Temple (46:1-10) was a prophetic description of a Temple with a different purpose than Herod's. It is doubted whether Herod ever consulted Ezekiel when building the Second Temple. He was superficially religious, and only consulted the Jewish leaders on nefarious occasions (e.g. Inquiry about Bethlehem concerning baby Jesus's birth).
Herod's TempleIn Herod's Temple there was indeed a "wall of separation" keeping the Gentiles out of the Temple proper. They were limited to the vast courtyard complex. This is specifically mentioned by Paul in Ephesians 2:14. (A sign with the warning notification to the Gentiles has been discovered!)

Now in Christ Jesus, you who sometimes were far off are made nigh by the blood of Christ. For He is our peace who has made us both one, and has broken down the middle wall of partition between us! (Ephesians 2:13-14)

The Temple building itself had a section in its corners where women could "observe" the sacrificing of the animals, or bring offering to the priests. Only men were allowed to go farther, and the priests could enter the Holy Place to perform their daily functions (Light the candlestick, present the showbread, etc.). Only the high priest could enter the Holy of Holies one day a year.
[See Alfred Edersheim, The Life and Times of Jesus the Messiah (2 volumes) for a thorough description.]
Solomon's TempleAs far AS the FIRST TEMPLE, prepared by David and built by Solomon, the many regulations and restrictions introduced by the strict Pharisees and their Seminaries were not yet enacted. But still, only the High Priest was allowed to enter the Holy of Holies, one time a year in Solomon's Temple. This was patterned after the mobile Tabernacle that was carried by the Israelites during the 40 years' wandering. The Holy of Holies was restricted.
The regular Levites (priests) would have access to the Holy Place, but not the common people of Israel.
Outside the Holy Place there was the large Altar and the Brazen Basin. And the King with all his attendants were allowed there. Then there were the people who sang and worshipped. David made sure that there was plenty of exuberant worship, led by organized choirs and orchestras!

The priests brought in the Ark of the Covenant of the LORD to its place...to the Most Holy Place...


And it came to pass when the priests were come out of the Holy Place (for all the priests that were present were sanctified, and did not then wait by designated course...and the Levites which were the singers...with their sons and brethren...having cymbals and psalteries and harps, stood at the east end of the Altar, and with them an hundred and twenty priests sounding with trumpets...


And Solomon stood before the Altar of the LORD in the presence of all the congregation of Israel, and spread forth his hands... (2 Chronicles 5:7-12, 6:12)

From the record of the Chronicler it is seen that the priests were allowed in the Holy Place.  And the "laymen" (King and people and Levitical singers) were allowed in the courtyard where the Altar was positioned.
It was in this courtyard that the people came with their sacrificial animals in tow, to offer to the priests to sacrifice. (There is no mention of an additional "wall of separation" to keep out the Gentiles.)
